# How to override unlink method for sale order in odoo10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, unlink, raiserror

Hello all i try to override unlink method of sale order line. Function called but raise UserError validation not removed.

**Odoo default function:**

```py
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    if self.filtered(lambda x: x.state in ('sale', 'done')):
        raise UserError(_('You can not remove a sale order line.\nDiscard changes and try setting the quantity to 0.'))
    return super(SaleOrderLine, self).unlink()
```

**Custom Override function:**

```py
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    if self.filtered(lambda x: x.state in ('sale', 'done')):
        pass
    return super(test, self).unlink()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you inherit a model and override a method. And you call super odoo keep the chaning.

Means in your case odoo calls `your method --> sale.order method --> models.Model method`

From what i understand you want to pass the validation means you don't want odoo to call unlink  `your unlink method ---> models.Model unlink`

Don't use super try this i think it should work if not i will show an other solution

```
    return models.Model.unlink(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Cherif suggested, you can by pass any of the step in the `super` inheritance workflow. 
In your case, if you want to call straightly the `models.Model unlink` method, try this way:

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    if self.filtered(lambda x: x.state in ('sale', 'done')):
        pass
    return super(models.Model, self).unlink()
```

Something similar has been discussed in [How can override write method without executing the super write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323752/how-can-override-write-method-without-executing-the-super-write)

Hoping that's answered your question